# Android Studio suddenly not resolving symbols associated with braintree (external) library?

Tags: android, braintree

I have been using Braintree for over a month and everything was working fine. Suddenly today none of the Braintree-related files are recognized and the import statements aren't as well.

I am using the basic code seen in [the setup here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/android+php/sdk/client/setup), and have not changed it (worked before, doesn't work now, not even for backed up versions/new projects).

Here are my errors:

[image: errors]

Here is the library:

[image: file listing]

I include the above because something strange that I noticed is that one of the library files is named: `src.com.braintreepayments.api.dropin`
is this naming perhaps a mistake? if so is that on my end, or Braintree's? I can't seem to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a packaging issue when Braintree added Eclipse support. Version 1.0.5 is being synced to Maven Central right now to fix this problem.

If your dependency specifies version 1.+ of the library, the issue will be resolved as soon as the sync finishes, usually in 2-3 hours.

Comment: I did a gradle project sync this morning and the errors are still there.  The library is still listed as 1.0.4.  Do I need to do anything else or is it still getting synced on Braintree's end?

Comment: You may need to clear your cache http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.braintreepayments.api%7Cbraintree%7C1.0.5%7Caar

Comment: Can I still use the gradle or do I need to use Maven?  Even when I clear my cache gradle still downloads 1.0.4

Comment: gradle is fine. What location do you have set for the maven central remote?

Comment: Is that found in the top level build.gradle file?  In that case I have this line of code: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'

Comment: Those are the dependencies, what I'm asking about is in the repositories block. On a side note, are you still not getting 1.0.5? Have you tried pinning it to 1.0.5 temporarily to see if it will resolve it?

Comment: I'm still not getting 1.0.5.  When I pin it to 1.0.5 in the build.gradle, the 1.0.5 library does load, but I still have errors.  Same thing for 1.0.4, however when I pin it down to 1.0.3, the problem is fixed.  But that's short term, I still want the new library to work.

Comment: When you pull down 1.0.5, what shows up in your external libraries list? Under braintree-1.0.5 do you see braintree-1.0.5.zip or just classes.jar and a res directory? I just cloned https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android and changed the Demo to depend on com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+ and it resolves 1.0.5 correctly and there are no errors. You may want to try to do the same.